# перевод даты из UNIX

Tags: android

я получаю с сервера дату в UNIX формате и UTC. Если использовать этот код

```
String result = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new Date(longUNIXDate * 1000));
```

, то получается корректное локальное время. Но должно быть -3 часа. Android научился переводить время в текущую локаль?
для примера 1546520963 код выдает время 16:09, а сайт для перевода 13:09:23 GMT

Comment: `new SimpleDateFormat(...)` с каким часовым поясом создается? У вас 16:09, а в Лондоне 13:09 :)

Comment: без указания пояса. выше весь код, который касается SimpleDateFormat. Я понимаю) поэтому и интересно откуда тянется инфа о поясе (к gps есть доступ у приложения, если это важно)

Comment: По умолчанию берется часовой пояс пользователя из системы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот так будет работать:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
String result = sdf.format(new Date(longUNIXDate * 1000));
```

Хотите получить время в нужном часовом поясе, выставьте его. По умолчанию берется системный.

Answer (score 0):

Вот код на `C#`, адаптировать под Яву не составит труда.

```
        public static Int32 GetUnixTimeStamp(this DateTime time)
        {
            return Convert.ToInt32((time - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0)).TotalSeconds);
        }
        public static DateTime GetDateTimeFromUnixTimeStamp(this Int32 time)
        {
            return (DateTime)(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)).AddSeconds(time);
        }
```

Comment: вопрос скорее не в способе реализации, у меня код работает, как нужно) просто хочу понять КАК он работает. т.е. android сам определяет где я и по этим данным добавляет часы к времени 13:09:23 GMT?

Comment: @Ксения, если часовой пояс не задан методом [`setTimeZone(TimeZone zone)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat#setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone)), то форматер берёт [`TimeZone.getDefault()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) Ну а дефолтный - это заданный в настройках аппарата (вручную или автоматически из сети провайдера).

Comment: т.е. время по гринвичу (полученное с сервера) автоматически приводится к дефолтному поясу (прибавлением или вычитанием часов), так?

Comment: Примерно так, хотя это зависит от настроек, лучше ориентироваться на дефаулт дату прибора. И можно взять значение с сервера, и значение с прибора, сравнить, вычесть или добавить.. Только вот зачем это надо, вот в чем вопрос.